# how to say "thank you in advance" in a letter

Tags: salutation, letter, etiquette

In English letters/emails to strangers we often use the phrase "thank you for your time" as a way to preemptively thank the receiver for answering. Is there an equivalent phrase in German?

Comment: Das sind für mich 2 unterschiedliche Fragen. Zeit wende ich schon beim Lesen auf - mit "im Vorraus" hat das nichts zu tun.

Comment: "Thank you in advance" is often considered rude. You might want to avoid using it.

Comment: You mean in German, right? It is very polite in English. It does not assume an answer and shows appreciation just for the act of reading the letter in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

> Bla bla bla, *könnten Sie bitte* blabla bla.
>
> **Vielen Dank für ihre Bemühungen!**
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen
>   Hans Maier

*Thank you for your efforts!*

Or just

> **Vielen Dank!**

*Thank you!*

You also might use

> **Vielen Dank im Voraus!**

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2):

I usually do it this way:

> ...
>
> Könnten Sie mir das [bitte] als PDF schicken?
>
> Danke schön und freundliche Grüße
>
> Your name

Answer (score 0):

A German teacher just corrected my letter and added the following note at the end:

> ...
>
> Danke im Voraus für Ihre Anwort
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen,
>
> ...

`Danke im Voraus für Ihre Anwort` is literally "thanks ahead of time for your reply".

Comment: There shall be no comma after "Mit freundlichen Grüßen".

Comment: You've corrected my teacher, then! :D Thank you.